# Validate data before performing LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on a simple import script that handles a .txt file and then uploads the contents to my database through `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

The query is done through `PHP/PDO`.

```
 $status = $pdo->exec(
  "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $file . "'
      IGNORE
      INTO TABLE `polizas`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
      IGNORE 1 LINES
      (`seccion`, `propuesta`, `poliza`, `endoso`, `tipo_endoso`, `desc_tipo_endoso`, `pol_que_renueva`, `iva_cond`, `tipo_doc`, `nro_doc`, `apellido`, `domicilio`, `cod_postal`, `telefono`, `localidad`, `provincia`, `fecha_emision`, `fecha_inicio`, `fecha_vcto`, `canal_pago`, `desc_canal_pago`, `origen`, `productor`, `organizador`, `moneda`, `item`, `marca`, `modelo`, `cero_Km`, `motor`, `chasis`, `patente`, `tipo_carroceria`, `desc_tipo_carroceria`, `cobertura`, `desc_cobertura`, `cod_acc1`, `desc_acc1`, `valor_acc1`, `cod_acc2`, `desc_acc2`, `valor_acc2`, `cod_acc3`, `desc_acc3`, `valor_acc3`, `cod_acc4`, `desc_acc4`, `valor_acc4`, `suma_aseg`, `prima`, `recarg`, `der_emision`, `sellos`, `imp_tasas`, `otros`, `bonif`, `iva`, `adminis_financ`, `premio`, `cant_cuotas`, `ajuste`, `tipo_vehiculo`, `desc_tipo_vehiculo`, `codigo_uso`, `descripcion_uso`, `ano_fab`, `nro_prestamo`, `vcto_cuota1`, `vcto_prestamo`, `tipo_prestamo`, `tipo_operacion`, `seccion_pol_paquete`, `poliza_pol_paquete`)"
 );
```

The above code works. The issue is that the user can upload *ANYTHING* (image, pdf, .exe, etc.) and more often than not the script will successfully insert all of that junk data into my database.

I've limited server-side what type of files the user can submit, but this can easily be bypassed by renaming the file to .txt and submitting again.

I'm looking for an efficient way to check if the data the user is trying to submit corresponds to what my database is expecting to receive.

Comment: Always try and use placeholders like `:file` instead of `'".$file."'` as the placeholders will *always* escape things properly.

Comment: You're going to have to scan the content with PHP before inserting. MySQL has no idea what an EXE is, but, as an example, the `file` command does if you're on a Linux-type system.

Comment: Good point, I missed the placeholder bit, thank you. As for what I mean by EXE and stuff, I mean any type of files ranging from images, to PDFs, to even executable files (.exe) being successfully inserted if submitted by the user unless I check for file extension in the script. That part is taken care of, but not the one where the user can submit any of that stuff simply renaming them to .txt.

Comment: The extension is meaningless. What you want to do, at the absolute least, is scan for "magic bytes" using a tool like [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) if not test that the file has, for example, some sort of header text that matches expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to read the first line of your file before send it to mysql. And check that the content of this line is what you expect to be.

```
$fn = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
$result = fgets($fn);
if ($result == "seccion,propuesta,..."){
//Proces file
}
fclose($fn);
```